# Android Studio adds entire package name for every class instead of importing

Tags: android, android-studio

Hey I'm not sure what happened but I refactored an Android project of mine recently. When I type the name of a new class the drop down menu appears as usual, prompting me to import it on the fly.

The weird thing is when I press enter halfway through typing the name of my new class, instead of importing the class, it just inserts the entire package name.

i.e.:

```
MyObject object = new com.example.MyObject();
```

Has anybody experienced this before?

Comment: did you try to restart the android studio ?

Comment: I did and initially it didn't fix it, but after waiting a bit it seems to have gone away. Strange haha, thanks for the reply :-)

Comment: hehheee... its going grazy sometimes.. wlcm...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This happened to me recently. My solution was to uncheck the "Use fully qualified class names" option under `File` --> `Settings` --> `Editor` --> `Code Style` --> `Java` --> `Imports` (tab)